# Сложный ListView

Tags: android, json, listview

Вообщем есть json данные(из wall.get контакта). Пытаюсь их вывести в listview(типа стена ВК, в приложении). Вопрос. Как работать со сложными структурами данных(была идея распарсивать в многомерный массив) но как потом выводить в listview. Вообшем подскажите, куда копать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно описать модель объекта JSON
Для начала возьмите JSON попроще.

```
{
      "response": {
        "count": 3,
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Title 1",
            "text": "Text 1"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Title 2",
            "text": "Text 2"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Title 3",
            "text": "Text 3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Для такого JSON модель будет выглядеть примерно так

Сперва описываем модель для элемента массива

```
public class Item {
    long id;
    String title;
    String text;
}
```

Идем на уровень выше, модель для контейнера элементов

```
public class Response {
    int count;
    List<Item> items;
}
```

Далее берем библиотеку типа [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), кормим JSON парсеру и получаем инициализированную модель.

**UPD**

Что бы распарсить JSON и получить модель с помощью **Gson**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);
```

А дальше дело техники, создаете адаптер который будет работать с элементами типа `Item`.

Для JSONa контачки создаете модели и в адаптере накручиваете логику. То есть смотрите на поле `type: 'photo'` значит вам надо отображать фотки, инфлейтите лэяут для фоток.

Comment: С моделями разобрался, теперь  проблема с парсингом. Вы сказали, что нужно использовать парсер, но я решил сам распарсить через JSONArray, JSONObject, и теперь понимаю,что это очень сложно(особенно со сложно структурными  данными) Можете пояснить как именно через сторонний парсер можно справится с этим?

Comment: Добавил как получить модель из json'а с помощью GSON, и добавил ссылку.